# NextNProgress remove spinner

Tags: next.js

I use `nextjs-progressbar`. But I can't hide spinner.  I'm trying to remove the spinner like this but it doesn't work:

```
#nprogress .spinner {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice parameter showSpinner inside options:

```
<NextNProgress options={{ showSpinner: false }} />
```